# Laravel 5.3 Pagination Total number of pages

Tags: php, laravel, count, pagination, paginator

I have a Paginator instance $paginator in Laravel App, I want to display 'Last' in pagination, so I need a link to the last page. How to get the last page number in laravel 5.3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `$results->lastPage()` paginator method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Comment: $results is what instance? because if I use paginator->lastPage()  I get this error Method lastPage does not exist.

Comment: `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

Comment: Thanks! Got it, used simplePagination so it wasnt available